# Select Distinct records (with a total count) that also may have similarities

Tags: sql

Not sure if this is possible but basically I have a table that has 2 columns: ID and Category.  Some sample records look like this:

```
1 Accounting 
2 Accounting 
3 Accounting & Tax Preparation
4 Banks
5 Banks & Financial Services
6 Real Estate
7 Real Estate - Commercial
8 Real Estate - Commercial & Residential
9 Real Estate
```

What I want to produce is a list that selects the category only once but counts how many occurrences of each one and can also eliminate duplicates that are very similar. So the result should look something like:

```
Real Estate - 4
Accounting - 3
Banks - 2
```

What I have now is:

```
    SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT(category), Count(*) as c " & _
      "FROM myTable " & _
      "GROUP BY category" & _
      "ORDER BY c DESC, category"
```

So it has all of the similar ones listed by themselves instead of grouped in with the other similar ones.  I know I can use the "LIKE" keyword with wildcards but when you dont know what the possible categories will be, how would you write it?

Any advice appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What if a category is `State`, does it belong to `Real Estate`?

Comment: `eliminate duplicates that are very similar.` define _very similar_

Comment: Easiest thing to do is create another column to group them by. Like `CategoryType` or something and then use some human deduction to categorize them all quickly, then you can easily write code against it.

Comment: Good question Tim.  It shouldn't belong to Real Estate but it does fall in with the LIKE query. I can't really add a new column this table and very similar meaning like "Real Estate" and "Real Estate - Residential". To throw another wrench in it, sometimes there could be misspellings. So I would like "Economic Development" and "Economic Davelopment" to be grouped together.

Comment: How about if you grouped by first word?  Would that give you what you want?  if that works let me know

Comment: If there is no space after the first word how would you know where to stop?  I mean what if the category is only 1 word long? I would rather do it by a certain number of characters even though that's still not going to be perfect but it's better than I have it now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Except for `Real Estate` how many groups have an extra space?  You could use `CHARINDEX` to locate the space (assuming MS SQL) and then group by the characters left of that.

`SELECT LEFT(Category, LEN(Category) - CHARINDEX(' ', Category)), COUNT(*) FROM myTable GROUP BY LEFT(Category, LEN(Category) - CHARINDEX(' ', Category))`

Comment: some have spaces, some do not.  But you may be on to something!  Could I just do a compare to the first 4 or 5 characters of the category?  Those that match, group together and add to the count?

Comment: So when the records are displayed how does it know what to write out? Does it do Real Estate or Real Estate - Commercial?

Comment: if you use my code above you should see everything to the left of the first space and then a count of that occurrence.  The only issue you could run into would be items with an identical first word.  So `Red Cars` and `Red Trucks` would be grouped together.